# Will an Ubuntu terminal in windows10 be compatible with Fedora/RedHat server?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have downloaded the Ubuntu app in my windows10 laptop as an alternative to Putty or some other kind of emulator. With the ubuntu terminal I would be ssh'ing into my institutions server which is run with fedora/redhat. It looks like I can peak around the server just fine, but I don't have any data to test yet...

Should I anticipate/will there be any problems accessing and working on the fedora/redhat server with an ubuntu terminal?

I'm new and this is a really small company so I'm just trying to get settled in before I start any major projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard, if not impossible to say there will be no incompatibilities of any kind. However, ubuntu and fedora/centos/redhat use the same ssh software, OpenSSH, and use quite recent versions of it... so comparability on a protocol level should be quite high. And once you are SSHed into a remote session what utilities and such you have on your local host is more or less irrelevant.

However, to be clear, you will not be using an ubuntu terminal. You will be using the windows terminal. Windows Services for Linux uses the same Windows terminal that PowerShell and CMD.exe use.

That said, the Windows terminal is quite technically capable if feature simplistic. It supports 256 colors, UTF-8 characters and control codes, and even mouse input for terminal applications that support it (elinks, midnight commander, tmux, etc). And, in my own tests, it seems to be plenty compatible with color codes and such sent by linux terminal application. You should probably pickup a copy of the font used in the ubuntu gui terminal (DejaVu Sans Mono) and configure the Windows terminal to use that. But I wouldn't expect any debilitating issues.

Comment: Your answer (sorry I can't upvote) sounds like what I expected. I have a fairly rudimentary understanding of computer infrastructure, but I expect that other unix-systems are able to "talk" to each other perfectly fine, with minor problems such as with accessing servers with Macs.

May I ask why you suggest picking up the Ubuntu gui font?

Comment: To make sure the font you are using has the same symbols with the same dimensions as the applications expect.  The use of Unicode art symbols to draw information (simple charts and graphs) to the screen has been growing more prevalent in recent years.

Answer (score -1):

I have never experienced an issue, and use the Ubuntu WSL on Win 10 Enterprise to ssh into virtual servers running RHEL 7 daily for development.  tmux, vim, joe, htop, etc., all "just work".

My WSL $TERM is "xterm-256color".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the purpose of sharing your $TERM ? Are there color issues?

Comment: There can be, but unless you start getting fancy with your shell configuration it is unlikely. The physical Linux terminal (what you would see with a monitor hooked up to the server) is limited to 16 colors... 8 colors and then 8 brighter versions of those same colors for "bold"... All virtual terminals, including Windows' terminal, support 16 color mode... though not all such terminals use exactly the same 16 colors. Almost all linux console applications with mission critical roles tend to stick to these 16 colors. For example, systemd makes use of "white" "bright red" and "bright green".

Comment: (cont.) However, you can run into problems with key bindings. If your terminal uses one set and the remote server uses another. Sticking to `xterm` or `xterm-256color` is usually safest. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap). And, for an example of "getting fancy with your shell configuration" look [here](https://imgur.com/a/XAqCKv1).